# Stripe difference between stripe.charges.create and stripe.transfers.create

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a platform account and some connected user account. So, I have account_id for each user. I want to send funds to some of the users. I searched in the stripe docs and saw two methods for doing this (maybe).

What is the different between `stripe.charges.create` and `stripe.transfers.create` ?

The [first](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/charges-api/connect#destination-charges) one:

```
const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 1000,
    currency: "eur",
    source: "tok_visa",
    transfer_data: {
    destination: "{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}",
    },
});
```

The [second](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers) one:

```
const transfer = await stripe.transfers.create({
  amount: 7000,
  currency: 'eur',
  destination: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  transfer_group: '{ORDER10}',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Charge` [0] moves funds from a payment method (e.g. a `Card`) to a Stripe account. A `Transfer` [1] moves funds from one Stripe account to a connected Stripe account.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/charges-api
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges

Comment: Which one do you think I should use?

Comment: You would only be able to use Transfers to move money from your Connect platform to a connected account. Charges are for charging a payment method.

Comment: But also I need to move money from a connected account to my platform account. So I found the debit account (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits) which is based on `stripe.charges.create`. Any idea? Also, I didn't understand what you said about `for charging a payment method`.

Comment: Account Debits are there own thing, yes. They use the Charges API but neither of the examples you provided above are related to Account Debits. The example in the docs you linked is what you'd use if you're going down that route.

Comment: You mean I can't use `stripe.charges.create` with source of `account_id` in order to move money from a user to my platform account? So how can it be possible?

Comment: You can follow the Account Debits docs (which uses a Charge API call as you mention). That is not the same as the call you showed in your original question, which is what I'm pointing out.